# PHP SimpleXMLIterator

Tags: php

I am using SimpleXMLIterator to parse some XML.
Doing a print_r shows that the SimpleXMLIterator Object created from the XML is like this:
{

```
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [id] => abc
        [type] => a
        [timestamp] => 2001-12-12
    )

[place] => US
[name] => Pete
[dob] => SimpleXMLIterator Object
    (
        [dd] => 03
        [mm] => 05
        [yyyy] => 1973
    )
```

}

which also contains a dob SimpleXMLIterator Object - i.e. a child element of the XML tag.

I iterate over this object using the following code, which is recurive as i cant be sure how deep each XML tag goes:

```
function _prepareSimpleXMLIteratorObj(SimpleXMLIterator $xmlIterator) {

foreach ($xmlIterator as $key => $value){
    // Count returns the number of children
    if ($value->count() > 0) {      
        $this->_prepareSimpleXMLIteratorObj($value);
    } else {
        $this->assocArray[$key] = (string)$value;
    }
}
}
```

assocArray is a member variable of the class.
This generates an assoc array from the Object.

Problem is when i use $value->hasChildren() instead of $value->count() i get false, even though $value->count() returns 3 for dob? Any ideas what i;m doing wrong?
Also if is do

```
if (($value instanceof SimpleXMLIterator))
```

i get false, even though dob is clearly a SimpleXMLIterator Object?

This method works but am just wondering about hasChildren and instanceof?

Here is the Sample XML

```
<tag id="abc" type="a" timestamp="2001-12-12">
    <place>US</place>
    <name>Pete</name>
    <dob>
        <dd>03</dd>
        <mm>05</mm>
        <yyyy>1973</yyyy>
    </dob>
</tag>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the sample XML being used?

Comment: Thanks - sample XML added into post above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the hasChildren method is not working for you because it is not doing what you think.  The key lies in this line in the documentation:

> This method checks whether the current SimpleXMLIterator element has sub-elements.

When it says **"current"** it means the actual SimpleXMLElement returned by the **current()** function as if you were iterating with foreach.  Remember SimpleXMLIterator is designed to be an "iterator"

So, when your algorithm gets to the dob node and you call $value->hasChildren() its really checking if the item $value->current() has any children.  So, in your example its checking whether the node /tag/dob/dd has any children, which it does not.